# How to synchronise two HLS-video players on a webpage

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8, hls.js

I want to embed two video players (currently using hls.js) on a webpage and play two “viewports” (two different HLS-playlists) from the same “scene” - in sync. Somehow I need a common time source setup for the players.

How can this be achieved? What components can help? Any projects on this?

Comment: The only reasonable way to do this is to have multiple video tracks in your stream.